# linux service TCP Gateway with service starting

Tags: linux, networking, services, tcp

Is there a service (linux) that starts the service on an incoming TCP request (if it does not already exist) and then forwards it to the application? For example, for a docker container that would only start if you want to use it. The container is stopped by cron at night.

Workflow:

- TCP client -> TCP server (Gateway)
- gateway check service is available
- if available then forward to
- if not available then

  - parking the TCP connection
  - start service
  - if started then forward connection to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, yes.

In 1986, the 4.3BSD Unix OS had the *inetd* service whose job was simply to listen for TCP connections and spawn the real service on activity. Inetd did not need to forward actual traffic – the service itself would inherit the real TCP socket and would be able to directly read/write the network data. However, the service *did* need to be written specifically to expect the socket to be already provided, instead of setting up everything on its own.

Many BSDs still have *inetd* (although it's mostly unused), and most Linux distributions have *xinetd* available. Additionally, every Linux distribution using systemd has this functionality available through *systemd.socket* units where it's called "socket activation".

(It *is* even possible to start whole containers this way, but the container manager also needs specific support for this feature. For example, systemd-nspawn makes it possible – unfortunately, as far as I know, Docker does not. This did not stop a few companies from using on-demand started containers in production, though.)

A proxy/gateway tool can be used to implement on-demand startup for programs (or containers) which don't support socket passing on their own. For example, systemd again has *systemd-socket-proxyd* which will start the real thing and relay connections to it (there's an [example with Podman](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/painless-services-implementing-serverless-rootless-podman-and-systemd) on the Red Hat blog, and here's [a Docker example](https://github.com/neppoliyant/lambda/blob/master/docker-socket-activation.md)); this can also be implemented with (x)inetd using ordinary netcat or socat as the relay.

Answer (score 1):

Podman supports  *socket activation*  of containers since Podman version 3.4.0 (released in September 2021).

If the service inside the container supports [*socket activation*](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activation.html), you can use **systemd** together with **Podman** to have systemd listen on the TCP socket. In case a client connects to the TCP socket, systemd will start Podman in such a way that the socket file descriptor is available to the Podman process. Podman will pass on the file descriptor to the container.

See the [Podman socket activation tutorial](https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/docs/tutorials/socket_activation.md#socket-activation-of-containers) that contains examples of how to run socket-activated containers with Podman.